# How to deal with "Unable to locate package" when installing a package?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

I've just switched to Ubuntu 20.04 (via a fresh install, due to an upgrade error). I'm trying to install a package that I used to use on Ubuntu 18.04 called [zoxide](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide) and I'm having a little difficulty. While I've been using Ubuntu for a little while, there's still lots I've not got to grips yet, including all the various ways of installing things (deb files, snap store, apt-get, wget).

This particular package, the install instructions say to use `apt install zoxide`, however that give me an:

> E: Unable to locate package zoxide

I've looked on a site called https://packages.ubuntu.com and can see it listed. Though I've noted that it mentions something called `hirsute` and `impish` which a quick Google suggests these are future versions of Ubuntu. My question is essentially how can I install it on Ubuntu 20.04? Is it just not currently available or do I need to follow a different path to install it?

Comment: I did a `rmadison zoxide` and I don't see it available for *focal* (or 20.04)   (which is the command like equivalent of the packages.ubuntu.com search you did... your system is *focal* thus your package search told you it wasn't available for your release).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your research is correct:

- The `zoxide` deb package was first added to Ubuntu in 21.04. It is not available as a deb in Ubuntu 18.04 nor Ubuntu 20.04 (nor Ubuntu 20.10). You can try using a wrong-version package on your 20.04 system, but it rarely works.
- There is no snap package matching the name `zoxide`, so no community members have created a snap for that software. If you are enthusiatic about the software, consider doing so.

To install on 18.04 and 20.04, follow the instructions to install from .tar.gz (tarball) in the software's upstream README file.

> If your distribution isn't included in the list below, you can download the binary from the Releases page and copy it to your $PATH.

Comment: Thank you :) Glad that my understanding of how it all works is slowly getting there, shame I didn't scroll down far enough in the README though :face_palm: